# Set up listener for return key ... from Android Bluetooth Sample code

Tags: android, return, listener

```
private TextView.OnEditorActionListener mWriteListener =
    new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the action is a key-up event on the return key, send the message
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            String message = view.getText().toString();
            sendMessage(message);
        }
        if(D) Log.i(TAG, "END onEditorAction");
        return true;
    }
};

 // Initialize the compose field with a listener for the return key
    mOutEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
    mOutEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(mWriteListener);
```

Why is mWriteListener a listener for the return key?